# npm install JSON.parse Unexpected token "}" (0x7D) in JSON at position 98 while parsing near "...: \"vite build\",\n },\n \"devDependenc..."

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install

hello i am installing `npm install` in my laravel project but gives me error

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token "}" (0x7D) in JSON at position 98 while parsing near "...: \"vite 
build\",\n    },\n    \"devDependenc..."
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\my_PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-16T13_59_50_980Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project>
```

i already tried to delete my `package-lock.json` in my **node_module** and
already did these

```
npm cache clear --force
npm cache verify
```

both of them gives me the same error

my using composer version

```
Composer version 2.4.4 2022-10-27 14:39:29
```

my npm version

```
npm version 9.1.1
```

my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "vite": "^3.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your package.json is not valid json, there is a `}` that is unexpected, try to use online json linter to see the issue like https://jsonlint.com/, if there is nothing sensitive in your file.

Comment: It seems there is a syntax error in your package.json file. Please edit your post and put your package.json file content.

Comment: hello  sir thank you for replying i already added my package.json.

Comment: it's that line: `"build": "vite build",`, you can't have a comma on the last property of an object in json

Comment: thank you already running now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the comma (,) after `vite build` and problem will be solved.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "vite": "^3.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you sir already running now, i will accept your answer after 8 minutes

Comment: @RayParas you're welcome my friend!

Comment: I was having the same issue on my prettierrc.json file. I removed the trailing comma and restarted the eslint server. All working now. Thanks